# Next.js: How to prevent flash of the Unauthorized route/page prior to redirect when implementing a private route?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, higher-order-components, next-router

Essentially I created a HOC for two pages in my Next.js app (i.e. `profile` and `dashboard`) two prevent users from accessing them if they're not authorized.

Example: `pages/profile.js`

```
import withAuth from "../components/AuthCheck/index";

function Profile() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Profile</h1>
    </>
  )
}


export default withAuth(Profile);
```

My Auth component/HOC:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useUser } from '../../lib/hooks'
import { PageLoader } from '../Loader/index'

const withAuth = Component => {
  const Auth = (props) => {
    const { isError } = useUser(); //My hook which is calling /api/user see if there is a user
    const router = useRouter()


    if (isError === 'Unauthorized') {
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && router.pathname === '/profile' || router.pathname === 'dashboard') router.push('/login')

      return <PageLoader />
    }
    return (
      <Component {...props} />
    );

  };

  if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    Auth.getInitialProps = Component.getInitialProps;
  }

  return Auth;
};

export default withAuth;
```

Now what is happening is if you happen to enter `/profile` or `/dashboard` in the browser URL bar, before the redirect you'll see the page for a second i.e. flash.

Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Because the redirect happens on the client-side - you'll briefly see the page generated on server first before it happens. The only way to prevent it is to redirect on the server-side.

Comment: @juliomalves Interesting. And thanks. So where would you put that logic to do that?

Comment: I'd recommend a read through [Authenticating Server-Rendered Pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication#authenticating-server-rendered-pages) and [Next.js Middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/middleware).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd consider making use of getServerSideProps on pages that need to be authed,  have a look at [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops%20https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops) . It'll run server side on a page per request.

Alternatively, it might make sense (depending on your project setup - especially if you have access to auth state in `_app.tsx_`) to render the auth component in your `_app`. More specifically, you could add a `protected:true` prop to the pages that are behind auth wall (using [static props](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)). Then in *app* you can check if a particular page has protected===true and redirect to auth component if the user isn't authed, for example:

```
            {pageProps.protected && !user ? (
                <LoginComponent />
            ) : (
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            )}
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, your post solved helped solve the problem!

Answer (score 4):

Based on what Juliomalves and Adrian mentioned I re-read the Next.js docs based on what they included, Always good to get a refresh.

That being said I tried what Adian posted.

In the `_app.js` file I did the following:

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { PageLoader } from '../components/Loader/index'

import { useUser } from '../lib/hooks'

import Login from '../pages/login'

const Layout = dynamic(() => import('../components/Layout'));

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const { user, isLoading } = useUser();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.replace(router.pathname, undefined, { shallow: true })
  }, [user])

  function AuthLogin() {
    useEffect(() => {
      router.replace('/login', undefined, { shallow: true })
    }, [])
    return <Login />
  }

  return (
          <Layout>
            {isLoading ? <PageLoader /> :
              pageProps.auth && !user ? (
                <AuthLogin />
              ) : (
                <Component {...pageProps} />
              )
            }
          </Layout>

  );
}

export default MyApp
```

So the `isLoading` prop from the SWR hook `useUser()` is a part of the first conditional ternary, While true you get the `<Loader/>`, when false you get the next ternary to kick of;

If the both the `auth` and `!user` props are true, the `AuthLogin` get rendered!

This is how I did it. I went into the pages I wanted private and used the async function *[getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation)* and created the prop `auth` and set it to `true`.

`/pages/dashboard.js` `Or whatever you want to be private`;

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    props: {
      auth: true
    },
  }
}
```

So back in `_app.js` when the pages are getting rendered the `getStaticProps` will, *as said docs* say:

> Next.js will pre-render this page at build time using the props
> returned by getStaticProps.

So when `pageProps.auth && !user` is reached in `_app`, that is where `auth` comes from.

Last two things:

You need this `useEffect` function in the `MyApp` component with the `user` prop from the hook in its dependency. Because that will keep the `URL` in sync/correct, between the redirects.

In `/pages/_app`, `MyApp` add:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    router.replace(router.pathname, undefined, { shallow: true })
  }, [user]);
```

In the `AuthLogin` component add:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      router.replace('/login', undefined, { shallow: true })
    }, []);
```

This ensures when  component gets rendered, the URL would be right.

I am sure if your page is changing frequently you'll have to look into [*getServerSideProps*](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getserversideprops) but for this solved my use case for static pages!

Thanks Juliomalves and Adrian!

Comment: Minor issue, I'd refactor and pull your AuthLogin function definition outside of your MyApp definition. Never a good idea to define a component inside of another component.